# inserting data using max +1 for a single record not the table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I need to update a row based on 2 parameters. My query so far will work using MAX for the field in question when working off the table.
I am having difficulty limiting the field to the record needed. The parameters are @ClientCode and @BillSeq to select the proper record

This is the query that works for the table

```
DECLARE @ClientCode char(4), @BillSeq int, @BillCommentSeq smallint, @Billcomment varchar(7500)
SELECT 
                @ClientCode = '00NJ'
                ,@BillSeq = 1
                ,@BillCommentSeq = (select MAX(BillCommentSeq) +1 from billcomment )
                ,@Billcomment =  (Select convert (varchar,getdate (),10) +' '+ 'Re-invoiced bill adjusting fees to 0' )


INSERT into dbo.BillComment VALUES (@ClientCode, @BillSeq, @BillCommentSeq, '' , @Billcomment)
```

I expected the query below to work however it does not

```
DECLARE @ClientCode char(4), @BillSeq int, @BillCommentSeq smallint, @Billcomment varchar(7500)
SELECT 
                @ClientCode = '00NJ'
                ,@BillSeq = 1
                ,@BillCommentSeq = (select MAX(BillCommentSeq) +1 from billcomment where clientcode = @ClientCode and billseq = @BillSeq )
                ,@Billcomment =  (Select convert (varchar,getdate (),10) +' '+ 'Re-invoiced bill adjusting fees to 0' )


INSERT into dbo.BillComment VALUES (@ClientCode, @BillSeq, @BillCommentSeq, '' , @Billcomment)
```

I get this error:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'BillCommentSeq', table
>   'database.dbo.BillComment'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
>   The statement has been terminated.

Using this modified statement

```
DECLARE @ClientCode char(4), @BillSeq int, @BillCommentSeq smallint, @Billcomment varchar(7500)
SELECT 
                @ClientCode = '00NJ'
                ,@BillSeq = 1
                ,@BillCommentSeq = (select MAX(BillCommentSeq)  from billcomment) +1 where clientcode = @ClientCode and billseq = @BillSeq )
                ,@Billcomment =  (Select convert (varchar,getdate (),10) +' '+ 'Re-invoiced bill adjusting fees to 0' )


INSERT into dbo.BillComment VALUES (@ClientCode, @BillSeq, @BillCommentSeq, '' , @Billcomment)
```

The error is this:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Comment: The "My" in MySQL does not stand for "Mycrosoft".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        DECLARE @ClientCode char(4), 
                @BillSeq int, 
                @BillCommentSeq smallint, 
                @Billcomment varchar(7500)

       Set      @ClientCode = '00NJ'
       Set      @BillSeq = 1

      SELECT @BillCommentSeq=Max(BillCommentSeq) 
      FROM billcomment 
      where clientcode = @ClientCode and billseq = @BillSeq

       IF @BillCommentSeq Is NUll 
           SET @BillCommentSeq=1
       Else 
           Select @BillCommentSeq = Max(BillCommentSeq) + 1 
           FROM   billcomment 
           where  clientcode = @ClientCode 
                  and billseq = @BillSeq 

          Select   @Billcomment =  (Select convert (varchar,getdate (),10) + 'Re-     invoiced bill adjusting fees to 0' )
          Print @Billcomment

           INSERT into BillComment
           Select @ClientCode,@BillSeq,@BillCommentSeq,@Billcomment

          Select * from BillComment
```

Comment: Thank you for the effort    however this too did not work   the error received is as follows      Incorrect syntax near '='.   I believe the is from this section  Select @BillCommentSeq = Max(BillCommentSeq)   I know this is a real brain buster

Comment: Edit my Script and copy it i'm sure you will get the output

Comment: That worked    Thank you so much    now I need to study it so i understand it

Answer (score 0):

Does the Billcomment table already have records? If not, or if none match the where clause, then Max() will return NULL. Wrap the statement with isnull() (not sure if that exists in MySql actually, but otherwise I'm sure it has a counterpart in MySql.

As for the incorrect syntax error, this is basically the query:

```
(select MAX(BillCommentSeq)  from billcomment) +1 
  where clientcode = @ClientCode and billseq = @BillSeq )
```

Note how the initial opening brace is closed after `from billcomment`. The rest of the statment `+1 where ....` is **outside** the `(select MAX(BillCommentSeq)  from billcomment)` part and is thus invalid syntax.

Remove the `)` before +1 and that should get rid of the invalid syntax error.

Comment: Thank you for the thought however I now get the following error    Incorrect syntax near '+'.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @ClientCode char(4), @BillSeq int, @BillCommentSeq smallint, @Billcomment varchar(7500)
SELECT 
            @ClientCode = '00NJ'
            ,@BillSeq = 1
            ,@BillCommentSeq = (select MAX(BillCommentSeq) +1 from billcomment where clientcode = @ClientCode and billseq = @BillSeq )
            ,@Billcomment =  (Select convert (varchar,getdate (),10) +' '+ 'Re-invoiced bill adjusting fees to 0' )


INSERT into dbo.BillComment VALUES (@ClientCode, @BillSeq, IFNULL( @BillCommentSeq,0), '' , @Billcomment)
```

Comment: Thank you    I tested this as well   this returns the error       Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'BillCommentSeq', table 'database.dbo.BillComment'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

All the queries are the set operations so they are not sequential ones. The select in which you set the max +1 value may not 'know' about the `@ClientCode` and `@BillSeq` values. Try to split the `SELECT` into two:

```
DECLARE @ClientCode char(4), @BillSeq int, @BillCommentSeq smallint, @Billcomment varchar(7500)

SELECT @ClientCode = '00NJ',
       @BillSeq = 1

SELECT @BillCommentSeq = (select max(BillCommentSeq)+1 from billcomment where clientcode = @ClientCode and billseq = @BillSeq),
       @Billcomment = (select convert(varchar, getdate(), 10) +' '+ 'Re-invoiced bill adjusting fees to 0' )


INSERT into dbo.BillComment VALUES (@ClientCode, @BillSeq, @BillCommentSeq, '' , @Billcomment)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below code.

```
DECLARE @ClientCode char(4), @BillSeq int, @BillCommentSeq smallint, @Billcomment varchar(7500)
SET  @ClientCode = '00NJ'
SET  @BillSeq = 1

SELECT @BillCommentSeq = MAX(ISNULL(BillCommentSeq,0)) +1 from billcomment 
 WHERE clientcode = @ClientCode and billseq = @BillSeq 
                ,
SELECT @Billcomment = convert (varchar,getdate (),10) +' '+ 'Re-invoiced bill adjusting fees to 0' 


INSERT into dbo.BillComment VALUES (@ClientCode, @BillSeq, @BillCommentSeq, '' , @Billcomment)
```